# How do I automate Python to navigate to other directories

Tags: python, command-line, automation

I am trying to make a code in Python where when it runs it will search a directory and its sub-directories for files ending with a file extension ".pdm". I want to note this is not on a personal computer but on a cloud provider. The variable current_dur is just a starting point to narrow down the search. The directory has to go at through at least 3 more folders in its sub-directories.

```
import os    
current_dur = r'\\dmn1.MIR.com\MIRFILE\FS159\FIRSCODB\IR Data Modeling\PIR\IR - Information Report'

for item in os.listdir(current_dur):
    if not os.path.isfile(item):
        for file in os.listdir(item):
            if file.endswith('.pdm'):
                print(file)
```

It returns the error message `[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Archive'`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I edited it. But my question is how do I navigate to other directories in Python. I want to automate this because I am looking for 200 .pdm files that are dispersed in over 20 different directories.

Comment: See [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: I think your issue is that "current_dur" is not a valid path. Try to display your current location os.path.abspath("./"), then try to move from one directory from another until you find where the path is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `os.walk()`?

```
import os    

current_dur = r'\\dmn1.MIR.com\MIRFILE\FS159\FIRSCODB\IR Data Modeling\PIR\IR - Information Report'

pdm_files = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(current_dur):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pdm'):
            pdm_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: When I used this it then gave an error of, 'str' object has no attribute 'endwith'.

Comment: `endwith()` should be `endswith()` - copy and pasted from your code block. I've corrected it now.